# Solve the double integral $\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-4y^2}}\left(3y^2-2+2yx^2\right)dxdy\:$

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-4y^2}}\left(3y^2-2+2yx^2\right)\,dx\,dy.$$
I think you need to be solved by the transition to polar coordinates:

\begin{cases}
x=r\cos(\phi),\\ 
y=r\sin(\phi)
\end{cases}

Comment: Revised your polar coordinates in the form: $x=r\cos(\phi),\ \ y=\frac{1}{2}r\sin(\phi)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x=r\cos(\phi)$ and $y=\frac{1}{2}r\sin(\phi)$. Then the Jacobian is $\frac{1}{2}rdrd\phi$. Then
$$
\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-4y^2}}^{\sqrt{1-4y^2}}\left(3y^2-2+2yx^2\right)\,dx\,dy= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}(...)\frac{1}{2}rdrd\phi.
$$

Comment: And what does it an ellipsis?

Comment: The ellipsis converts to a unit circle.

Comment: Did not understand you :(

Comment: You have $x^{2}+4y^{2}=1$ (the ellipsis) and $x^{2}+4y^{2}=r^{2}\cos^{2}(\phi)+4(\frac{1}{4})r^{2}\sin^{2}(\phi)=r^{2}$ which means $r=1$ (the unit circle- in polar coordinates-).